# Como criar um loading sem AJAX

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um botão de download que faz uma requisição GET que faz um Download.
Isso acontece tudo na mesma página, mas sem AJAX.

Não é usando a tag `download`. É usando o `Laravel` que internamente faz o serviço de download.

Gostaria que ao apertar o botão de Download, aparecesse uma mensagem no botão **mesmo "Aguarde..."**.

Quando terminasse o processo de carregamento da página e iniciasse o download, voltasse a mensagem anterior do botão.

Tentei fazer assim, mas não funciona:

```
$('.btn-export').on('click', function(){
    $(this).text('EXPORTANDO...');

    $(window).on('load', function(){
        $('.btn-export').text('EXPORTAR');
    });
});
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Se pudesse dizer qual parte não funciona: o de alterar o texto ou de voltar o texto, ou os dois.

Comment: A que volta o texto.

Comment: Veja, o $(window).on(load... não vai surtir efeito dentro do onclick do botão... coloque-o fora para que a página possa executa-lo quando for carregada

Comment: Não funciona. Já tentei.

Comment: Só pra ver se entendi: esse processo todo ocorre sem refresh da página?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, quando você clica no botão de *download*, a página é recarregada. É isso? Se sim, o que você deve fazer é atrasar o carregamento da página para que a exibição do `$(this).text('EXPORTANDO...');` seja visível. Caso contrário, a página vai recarregar e você vai perder todas as modificações dinâmicas no *DOM*. Esse atraso não é uma boa prática na minha opinião. Já o `$(window).on('load', ...);` não tem nenhuma utilidade dentro do escopo do botão.